# How to correctly use Array.map() for replacing string with alphabet position

Tags: javascript

Other SO 'Replace string with alphabet positions' questions didn't utilize map, which is what I'm trying to learn how to use to solve this.

Problem: 
Given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.
If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.
"a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.

What I've tried is: 
-looping over a new array instance and setting the index value to `String.fromCharCode()`
- taking input string making it lowercase
-splitting to array
-return array.map().join(' ')

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {

let alphabet = new Array(26);
for (let i = 0; i<26; ++i) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
  alphabet[i] = char;
}

text = text.toLowerCase();

let arr = text.split('');

return arr.map(element => { return element = alphabet.indexOf(element+1) }).join(' ');
}
```

expected it to return a string of alphabet positions, but got nothing at all. What is wrong with my implementation of Array.map()?

Comment: "nothing at all" really?

Comment: I think you're at least going to need to remove the 'element = ' portion of the second-to-last line

Comment: I guess you are looking for `alphabet.indexOf(element)+1` instead of `alphabet.indexOf(element+1)`. Other than that, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map()` last line of the function was returning the value of 
 an assignment.

```
return arr.map(element => { return element = alphabet.indexOf(element+1) }).join(' ');
```

Just `alphabet.indexOf(element)` would have sufficed.

This will give you the result you want:

```js
alphabetPosition = text => {
  let alphabet = new Array(26);
  for (let i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    let char = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
    alphabet[i] = char;
  }

  return text.toLowerCase().split('').map(element =>
    alphabet.indexOf(element)
  ).join(' ');
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("This is a string"));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 4):

In your map `element` would be a letter, `"a"` for example. Then you add (concat) 1 to it, which results in `"a1"` which is not in your alphabet. Also `element =` is unneccessary, `return`ing the position is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You've complicated the solution, the simplest approach would be to just find the charcode and return that.

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  let str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    str += (text[i] + (text.charCodeAt(i) - 96));
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: how is `str` the positions of each letter of the string in the alphabet if you're using `text.charCodeAt(i)`?

Comment: `text.charCodeAt(i) ` will return the char code of the character in the position `i`.
If your string is `jim`, then `text.charCodeAt(0)` will return the char code of `j`

Comment: Yeah, hence the `- 96` to normalize the values.

Answer (score 2):

I totally understand that is a coding challenge, interview question or likewise so if you really need to use map() you should only return the result of the callback passed to map as follows :

```
return arr.map(x => alphabet.indexOf(x) + 1).join(' ')
```

However reduce() seems more appropriate in your case :

```
return arr.reduce((ac, cv) => ac + (alphabet.indexOf(cv) + 1) + ' ', '')
```